# Creating templates by using generated URL

Tags: docusignapi

I have an application where business users wants to have their own NDA documents. I want to integrate docusign for that. However I just want to make it as simple as I can, it means that business user should be able to:

1. upload pdf/any doc document
2. setup signup boxes (page, arrangement)
3. save template for the future use (in perfect scenario I want to keep template ID in my database)

Business users doesn't want to create additional accounts or signup via docusign - so my question is:

**Is there any option to generate some kind of dedicated URLs for the template creators? or maybe I should thing about it in some different way?**

Thanks!

- REST API for creating templates
- DocuSign GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of this, but the URL have to be created on the fly by our app when they click something.
There are two things your app will do:

1. Allow users to create/edit templates. That's one type of activity, and for that you need to make these API calls:

- Create template - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/create-template/
- General recipient view for template

2. Allow users to send envelope from their template. This is a separate thing you do, it will assume the template exist and make a different API call to create an envelope from it:

- Create envelope based on template - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have 1 following question: how can I edit / add proper details to the template? because in the 1st step/API there is only direct call with the base64 upload?

Comment: The first step allows you to put all details in the template, but you can also make a PUT call to update a template if needed.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong but 1st I need to create template with some basic document/draft (Upload empty document via internal app) - then I should generate edit sender view for manage sign fields(tabs) by using docusin gui. After that I should generate envelopes by using that template for different users that business users wants to collaborate (by using NDA).

Comment: Correct, these are the 3 steps here. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! :) I can confirm that its working. I have probably last question according to the date. What can I do if I don't know who will be the signer but I want to select the place where he/she should sign in the document. If I create a template without a signer email then I cannot later on use envelope with the real one. The main idea behind that is to have a nda template with 2x boxes (owner & non business user). However on the template creation process I don't know yet who will be the non-business, I just want to setup sign in tabs properly.

Comment: I believe I figured it out - I'm adding only recipientId, routineOrder, roleName for non-business users to the template creation request. Later on, on the envelope creation I'm adding non-business templateRole entry with the user details :)

Comment: If you have further questions - please post new questions so others can help too. thanks.